# Only call method when a human changes an input - not when the method changes the input in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, websocket, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue and trying to build a form that calls an API when an input is changed to dynamically build and set other inputs. It's purpose is to select a vehicle.

When you select a make, it populates the model and year select fields with appropriate values from the API via WebSocket. These fields may be filled automatically from the VIN (vehicle identification number) and any field in the process may change other fields.

This is causing a feedback loop where an input is changed by another input which in turn, calls the API which sends back another set of data and changes something else.

How can I ensure that data is only set once after a human changes a field?

My Vehicle selection code:

```
<template>
  <div id="vehicleSelection">
    <h1 class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
    <b-field label="Make">
      <b-select placeholder="Select a make" v-model="make" @input="setMake(make)" id="makeSelect">
        <option
                v-for="make in make_list"
                :value="make"
                :key="make">
          {{ make }}
        </option>
      </b-select>
    </b-field>
    <b-field label="Model">
      <b-select placeholder="Select a model" v-model="model" @input="setModel(model)" id="modelSelect">
        <option
                v-for="model in model_list"
                :value="model"
                :key="model">
          {{ model }}
        </option>
      </b-select>
    </b-field>
    <b-field label="Year">
      <b-select placeholder="Select a model year" v-model="year" @input="setYear(year)" id="yearSelect">
        <option
                v-for="year in year_list"
                :value="year"
                :key="year">
          {{ year }}
        </option>
      </b-select>
    </b-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CommandClient from '../communication/command/CommandClient';
  import MessageHandler from '../communication/handler/MessageHandler';

  export default {
    name: 'VehicleSelection',
    methods: {
      setMake(make) {
        CommandClient.send(this.$socket, CommandClient.prepare('set_vehicle_make', ['make', make]));
      },
      setModel(model) {
        CommandClient.send(this.$socket, CommandClient.prepare('set_vehicle_model', ['model', model]));
      },
      setYear(year) {
        CommandClient.send(this.$socket, CommandClient.prepare('set_vehicle_year', ['year', year]));
      },
    },
    created() {
      this.$options.sockets.onmessage = (message) => {
        MessageHandler.handle(this, message);
      };
    },
    data() {
      return {
        title: 'Vehicle Selection',
        make_list: [],
        make: null,
        model_list: [],
        model: null,
        year_list: [],
        year: null,
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

There is some repetition here which will probably be refactored out but I'd like to just get it working first.

For context, the MessageHandler here takes a Vue component and sets data for it if the key is present in the API response:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

export default {
  /**
   * @param {Object} context
   * @param {MessageEvent} message
   * @return {void}
   */
  handle(context, message) {
    const messagePayload = JSON.parse(message.data);
    Object.entries(messagePayload).forEach((data) => {
      if (_.has(context.$data, data[0])) {
        context.$set(context, data[0], data[1]);
      }
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about your code since I don't know the specifics of it...

I would imagine you're getting a feedback loop if you're calling the API in response to *any* change made to a specific data property via `watch`; e.g. if you had code like this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    year: 2010,
  };
},
watch: {
  year() {
     // this.year changed either by user input or by any other means.
     // Calling API here...
     this.api();
  },
},
```

You're combining `v-model` and `@input` in your template; this will work although it's a bit confusing (`v-model` is just syntax sugar for `:value` and `@input`; will two `@input`s work? Yes, it turns out, but I digress).

If you only want to call the API in response to user input, then call the API in the `@input` handlers of the UI elements that you want to trigger the calls:

```html
<b-select :value="make" @input="setMake">

<!-- For a native DOM element, do this instead -->
<select :value="make" @input="setMake($event.target.value)">
```

```js
methods: {
  // This method is *only* called by @input
  setMake(make) {
    // Set this.make in response to user input
    this.make = make;

    // Call API here only; this.make can be changed by other means
    // but it won't trigger an API call in those cases
    this.api();
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks - I think maybe this issue is due to the websocket listener being used to set data rather than a typical REST scenario... I've been thrown on this project and it's _all_ very new to me coming from a PHP background. I'm getting a type error trying to use `@input="setMake($event.target.value)"`: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. How is `$event` computed?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, `$event.target.value` typically works for ordinary DOM elements (such as `<input>`, `<select>`, etc), but `<b-select>` is a Vue component so it wouldn't work. [`$event`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) contains the event args object (in the case of a native DOM element) or whatever arg was passed to [`$emit()`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) from the component. Try `setMake($event)` (or even just `setMake`) instead.

Comment: Ok - yeah that clears the error and code is looking leaner (thanks) but still the same feedback loop. I think my issue is boiling down to the WebSocket pattern of having an open `onmessage` listener which sets data in `created()` :-/

Comment: In what situation are you calling the WebSocket API? What triggers it? Is it in a `watch` handler? Or an event listener?

Comment: You can see it in my `methods` definition in the question: `CommandClient.send(this.$socket, CommandClient.prepare('set_vehicle_make', ['make', make]));` the client builds a JSON object in `.prepare` which is sent to the socket. When the application first starts it sends a `default_settings` message which gets/sets initial values.

Comment: (It might've helped if I scrolled down lol). It looks correct to me, although I don't know what the code for the `<b-select>` component is. It might be calling `$emit('input', value)` in response to `:value` changing instead of only in response to user input. If the former, then you have no way of distinguishing between user-input and the value being changed by code.

Comment: URGH. thanks - just tried with a plain old select and it's fine. I was using Buefy: https://buefy.github.io/#/ which is a vue wrapper for Bulma markup which must have been doing some daft magic. Sorry for putting you through this.